# Accessing Function On Another Struct

Tags: go

Using Go 1.11.x with the echo framework.

I have the following struct and function

```
type AccountController struct {
  ....
}

func (c *AccountController) ActiveAccountID() int {
  ....
  return 5
}
```

Now I want to access the `ActiveAccountID` from another struct, this is how i did it,

```
type TestController struct {
   Account *AccountController
}

func (c *TestController) AddData(ec echo.Context) error {
  ....
  id := c.Account.ActiveAccountID()     
  ....
}
```

But when I print / use the id var, it just gives me a memory pointer error?

I have tried the account controller to remove the pointer but i still got the memory pointer issue. So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: "memory pointer error" isn't a thing, can you post the actual error output you get?

Comment: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference <- sorry new to go, i just thought that was a memory pointer error?

Comment: Most likely `Account` is `nil` (hasn't been initialized).

Comment: Right ok, think i understand and will look into that - many thanks for the help

Comment: Before you call `c.Account.ActiveAccountID()`, you need to initialize `c.Account=&AccountController{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the structure of your struct

```golang
type TestController struct {
   Account *AccountController
}
```

Account is a pointer. It's inititalized to `nil`, so if you never set it to point to something, it will always be nil, and you will get a nil pointer dereference error when you try to call a method on it like this

```golang
// c *TestController
c.Account.ActiveAccountID()
```

How/when you set it depends on your use case.

Also depending on your usecase, you can change it from a pointer to an embedded struct

```golang
type TestController struct {
   Account AccountController
}
```

This way it's always inside the struct, but if you assign it from somewhere else it will be copied. Depending on your usecase, that might be undesireable.

Comment: This help me! Thanks